# Will one Foreign key to two tables cause confusion?

Tags: postgresql

If I have table A, and table B, and I have data that start off in table A but end up in table B, and I have a table C which has a foreign key that points to the primary key of A, but when the data get removed from A and ends up in table B, it should point to B instead (having the same id as A's data did). Will this cause confusion. Heres and example to show what I mean:

A (Pending results)
id =3

B( Completed Results)
null

C(user)
id = 1
results id = 3 (foreign key to both A and B)

After three minutes, the results have been posted.

A (Pending results)
null

B( Completed Results)
id = 3

C(user)
id = 1
results id = 3 (foreign key to both A and B)

Is there anything wrong with this implementation. Or would it be better to have A and B as one table? The table could grow very large which is what I am worried about. As separate tables, the reads to table A would be far greater than the reads to table B and table A would be much smaller, as it is just pending results. If A and B were combined into one table, then it would be both pending and a history of all completed results, so finding the ones which are pending would take much more time I assume. All of this is being done is postgresql if that makes a difference.

So I guess my question is: Is this implementation fine for a medium scale, or given the information I just said, should I combine table A and B (Even though B will grow infinitely large whereas A only contains present data and is significantly smaller).

Comment: If you use just use one table for all results, then a simple foreign key constraint can cover you. The results are results after all, so one entity, not two. So they belong in one common table. You can add a column designating the status (pending, completed) to that table. For performance you should first look into proper indexing.

Comment: "Is there anything wrong with this implementation" - Did you try it? https://rextester.com/YLMB57505

Comment: @NickBarnes, Sorry I'm a newbie but I really appreciate this. Had no idea it existed but I see that my implementation does not work

Comment: @Vikram: Happy to help! Sounds like you actually wanted a foreign key to _either_ A _or_ B, but there's no such thing. Though as David explained, a single table is a better design anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've already found that this does not work. I couldn't follow your example properly because "A", "B", and "C" never work for me. I suspect those kinds of formulaic labels are *better* than specifics for other people. You just can't win ;-) In any case, it sounds like you're facing a practical concern about table size, and are being tempted to use a design that splits a natural table into two parts. (Hot and old.) As you found, that doesn't really work with the keys in a system. The relational model (etc., etc.) doesn't have a concept for "this thing is a child of this or that." So, you're swimming up stream there. Regardless, this kind of setup is *very* commonplace in the wild, so much so that it's got a name. Well, several names. "Polymorphic Association" from Bill Karwin's *SQL Anti-Patterns* is common. That's a good book, and short, by the way. Similarly, "promiscuous association" is a term you'll see. Or sometimes you'll see the table itself listed as a "jump table", or a "hub", etc.

I suspect there's a reason this non-relational pattern is so widely used: It makes sense to humans. An area where the relational model is always a tight pinch is when you have things which are kinds of things. Like, people who are staff or student. So many fields in common, several that are distinct to their specific type. One table? Two? Three? Table inheritance in Postgres might help...at least it's trying to. Anyway, polymorphic relations are problematic in an RDBMS because *they're not able to be modeled or constrained automatically.* You need custom code to figure out that this record is a child of that table...or the other table. You can't bake that into the relations. If you're interested in various solutions to this design problem, Karwin's chapter is quite good, easy to read, and full of alternative designs. If you don't feel like tracking down the book but are a bit interested, check out this article from a few years ago:

https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database

Chances are, your interest right now is more day-to-day. Is sounds like you've got a processing pipeline with a few active records and an ever-increasing collection of older records. You don't mention your Postgres version, but you might have less to worry about than you imagine. First up, you could consider partitioning the table. A partitioned table has a single *logical* table that you talk to in your queries with a collection of smaller *physical* tables under the hood. You can get at the partitions directly, but you don't need to. You just talk to my_big_table and Postgres figures out where to look. So, you could split the data on week, month, etc. so that no one bucket every gets too big for you. In this case, the individual partitions have their own indexes too. So, you'll end up with smaller tables and smaller indexes under the hood. For this, you're best off using PG 11, or maybe PG 10. Partitioning is a big topic, and the Postgres feature set isn't a perfect match for every situation...you have to work within its limits. I'll leave it at that now as it's likely not what you need first.

Simpler than partitioning is an *awesome* Postgres feature you may not know about, partial indexes. This isn't unique to Postgres (SQL Server calls the same sort of feature a "filtered" index), but I don't think MySQL has it. Okay, the idea is really simple: Build an index that only includes rows that match a condition. Here's an example:

```
CREATE INDEX tasks_pending
          ON tasks (status)
       WHERE status = 'Pending'
```

If you're table has 100M records, a full B-tree has to catalog all 100M rows. You need that for a uniqueness check on a primary key...but it's big and expensive. Now imagine your 100M records have only 1,000 rows where status = pending. You've got an index with just those 1,000 rows. Tiny, fast, perfect. The beauty part here is that the partial index doesn't necessarily get bigger as your historical data set grows. And, shout out to historical data sets, they're *very* nice to have when you need to get aggregates, etc. in a simple search. If you split things into multiple tables, you'll need to write longer queries with UNION. (That wouldn't be the case with partitions where the physical division is masked by the logical partition master table.)

HTH

Comment: "*because "A", "B", and "C" never work for me*" - same here!

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful and super informative. I'm relatively new to DBs and don't understand a lot on how things work, but the way you explained it could not have been clearer and the chapter you provided seems promising. Thanks again!